# Input Field is Recognized by Selenium but Keys are not Being Sent

Tags: python, selenium, rpa

The input field is being recognized by Selenium (done using xpath), but I am not able to send any keys to it. There is no error, but the text I want written into the keys is not being shown in the search box. The input field is inside several divs and is in an iframe, but I'm pretty sure I took care of that. What can I do to fix this issue?

```
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/input")
search.send_keys("25%)")
```

[Picture of HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPZiM.png)

The input field doesn't have an ID and it doesn't have a type either, so I'm not really sure how else to find it besides xpath.

Comment: did you switch the driver to the iframe?

Comment: Yes, I did. I'm able to select other things inside the iframe, I just can't get the text to show in the input box for some reason.

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Have you tried a CSS selector like `div.search-input > input`?

Comment: Sorry, I did so because the html is deep inside many divisions. I will edit my original question. Do you mean I should try find_element_by_css_selector("div.search-input"). This is my first time trying Selenium so I have a lot to learn. I'm not sure what you mean by '>'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the difference between Java and Python but my suggestion is that you try using JavaScriptExecutor to enter the Keys:

Your Python code that gets the element:

```
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/input")
```

You basically pass the element this way in Java:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='<<Add your input String here>>';", search);
```

Many times, it works when SendKeys doesn't

Answer (score -1):

Use class to locate the div element:

```
search_div = driver.find_element_by_class_name("search-input")
search = search_div.find_element_by_class_name("text")
```

Btw:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

klass = "search-input"
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, klass)))
search_div = driver.find_element_by_class_name(klass)
search = search_div.find_element_by_class_name("text")
```

Comment: I tried this and got an error saying "element not interactable." I don't think I can send keys to the div itself? I thought I can only send keys to the input field, which isn't working for whatever reason.

Comment: that's still the div... you need the input inside of that div

Comment: Yea, still getting the same error "element not interactable." It's strange because there is no error in my original code with input but the text isn't showing up in the field

Comment: Sorry dude, I read it wrong before, your div is "search-input" class and after you've located it then just locate the element inside it by "text" class or "input" type.

Comment: That makes sense. How would you write the code to locate the input element inside the div field? Would I still use driver.find_element_by_class_name("text")?

Comment: You search **inside** `search_div`, I used that example with a class above, but any other call may take place too, like `search_div.find_element_by_tag_name("input")`

Comment: This works, selenium is able to identify the input box with no errors, but no text is actually being written into it. Same issue I was having before. I am using send keys function. Really appreciate the help btw!

Comment: Dunno, that's the way to do it, try with `search.send_keys("25%)\n")`.

Comment: Yea, I don't know why it isn't working. Thanks anyways!